# Terminal preferences

Tags: gnome-terminal

Couple of days ago I have seen username@hostname:~$ being changed by an arrow (similar to "->" without the gap) any idea on how this can be achieved ?

Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Seems the command you entered in the shell was not complete (e.g. no matched quotation marks, no matching `if ...fi` or `do...done` & the like. The shell asks this way for continuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit this in your `.bashrc`. In my case, it has a line that looks like this:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

From bash 4.2 and on, you can change it like so:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1=$'\u2192 '
fi
```

And then save the file and run `source ~/.bashrc` to get a prompt that looks like only an arrow[image: only an arrow]

**Stipulations:**

- Obviously, you would flip the if/else if you forced color prompt.
- You need to make sure your terminal runs UTF-8. [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) has a [good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25903/awesome-symbols-and-characters-in-a-bash-prompt) on how to do this in hex to prevent UTF-8 changes.